# How do I stop the display:block; behavior in this nav bar link that has the inline property?

Tags: html

I'm creating a digital portfolio for myself, and I have created a basic navigation bar, with ul/li styling, using css and html. The hover effect I want is almost there, but when you hover over the image, there is a white box behind the link text. From my understanding, that should only happen if the display property is set to block, since inline is the default, and I have property set to inline but it still behaves as if its block. Can you help?

This is my current css code:

```css
ul{
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
    border-width: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
    border-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
    font-family: "Raleway"; 
    font-size: 100%;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 9%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 100%;
    float:left;
}

li {
    display:inline;
}

li a{
    font-size: 28px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: #21cca5;
}
 
.active{
    color: #21cca5;
}

#extras{
    color:white;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: none;
}
 
#aoiti{
    color:white;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: none;
}
 
#aoitii{
    color:white;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: none;}

#home{
    color:white;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: none;
}
 
#gallery{
    color:white;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: none;
}
```

And my relevant html code:

```html
<ul id="linkBar">
 <li id="home"><p><a href="aoiti.html" class="active"><p>Home</a></p></div>
 <li id="aoiti"><p><a href="aoiti.html">AOIT I</a></p></li>
 <li id="aoitii"><p><a href="aoitii.html">AOIT II</a></p></li>
 <li id="extras"><p><a href="academics.html"> Extras</a></p></li>
 <li id="gallery"><p><a href="aoiti.html">Gallery</a></p></li>
 <p><br></p>
</ul>
```

Comment: Remove your `<p>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing css like this

```
li a:hover{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: #21cca5;
}
```

Change it to

```
li a:hover{ 
    color: #21cca5;
}
```